# Incorrect 'date modified' in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: files

When copying files of the same name between folders (and overwriting), or even renaming a single file, it seems the 'date modified' doesn't change, which is supremely annoying as you can imagine.

Is there some way to display and sort by the date *any* part of the file was modified in anyway?

Comment: As long as the content of the file doesn't change, moving or copying it doesn't change the source file modification date because the file has not been modified.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the 'touch' utility to change the file date/time.

   - From the command line interface, short version explanation: `$ touch --help`
   - For long version explanation: `$ info coreutils 'touch invocation'`
2. To display the contents of a directory, sorted by date: `$ ls -lS`

Answer (score 0):

There is something known as the hash value for each file. If you modify the file, the hash value will not be the same. You can check the md5sum hash value of a file.

`cd` in to the directory which contains your file and type the following command:

```
md5sum <filename>
```

Hope this'll help.